# Windows Phone 8 Can't Update listbox item in XML file after using hardware back button?

Tags: windows-phone-8

Hi All i have a list box and i am saving list box selected item in XML file thats working fine but the problem is that when i will close my app and reopen and add more value to list box my previous value is removed form the xml file and listbox also how i can save my current added value and previous value in xml file i am using following code :

and iam using following code

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="2" Margin="15,10,15,0">
    <ListBox Name="list_location" Tap="list_location_Tap"  Foreground="Black">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock x:Name="item_name" Text="{Binding description, Mode=OneWay}" Padding="5,15,5,15" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <ListBox Name="list_locationAdd" Background="Red"  Foreground="Black" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock x:Name="item_name" Text="{Binding description, Mode=OneWay}" Padding="5,15,5,15" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

and my back end code is follow:

```
 XmlWriterSettings x_W_Settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
 x_W_Settings.Indent = true;
 using (IsolatedStorageFile ISF = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
 {
     using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = ISF.OpenFile(filename, FileMode.Create))
     {
         XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Prediction>));
         using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, x_W_Settings))
         {                                        
             data.Add(new Prediction() { description = App.professionalId });
             list_locationAdd.ItemsSource = data;
             serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, data);
         }
     }
 }

 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (list_locationAdd != null)
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFile ISF = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream str = ISF.OpenFile(filename, FileMode.Open))
                    {
                        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Prediction>));
                        ObservableCollection<Prediction> data = (ObservableCollection<Prediction>)serializer.Deserialize(str);
                        if (list_locationAdd != null)
                        {
                            this.list_locationAdd.ItemsSource = data;
                            list_locationAdd.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                        }                            
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }          
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change in your code as per below :

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile ISF = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
 {
     using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = ISF.OpenFile(filename, FileMode.Create))
     {
         XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Prediction>));
         using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, x_W_Settings))
         {                                        
             data.Add(new Prediction() { description = App.professionalId });
             list_locationAdd.ItemsSource = data;
             serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, data);
         }
 }
```

Update in your current code :

```
IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.User | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly, null, null);
if (isoStore.FileExists(filename))
{       
    try
    {           
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, isoStore))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Prediction>));
            ObservableCollection<Prediction> data = (ObservableCollection<Prediction>)serializer.Deserialize(isoStream);
            this.list_locationAdd.ItemsSource = data;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) 
    { }
}
else
{
    try
    {   
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, isoStore))
        {
            XmlSerializer Serialize = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Prediction>));
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(isoStream, x_W_Settings))
            {
                data.Add(new Prediction() { description = App.professionalId });
                list_locationAdd.ItemsSource = data;
                Serialize.Serialize(writer, data);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { }
}
```

Hope this is helpful to you.